# Headers not found when referencing CocoaPods project from Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, build, cocoapods

I would like to include [iOS-WebP](https://github.com/seanooi/iOS-WebP) as a pod to my Swift project.

The pod spec reads

> source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
>
> platform :ios, '8.0'
>
> use_frameworks!
>
> pod 'iOS-WebP', '0.4'

In Swift, I use `import iOS_WebP` to use the library.

However, compilation fails with the relative header paths inside the library not resolving correctly:

```
<module-includes>:1:9: note: in file included from <module-includes>:1:
#import "/Users/.../Products/Debug-iphoneos/Pods/iOS_WebP.framework/Headers/Pods-iOS-WebP-umbrella.h"
        ^
/Users/.../Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Pods/iOS_WebP.framework/Headers/Pods-iOS-WebP-umbrella.h:3:9: note: in file included from /Users/.../Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Pods/iOS_WebP.framework/Headers/Pods-iOS-WebP-umbrella.h:3:
#import "UIImage+WebP.h"
        ^
/Users/.../Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Pods/iOS_WebP.framework/Headers/UIImage+WebP.h:10:9: error: 'WebP/decode.h' file not found
#import <WebP/decode.h>
        ^
/Users/...ViewController.swift:3:8: error: could not build Objective-C module 'iOS_WebP'
import iOS_WebP
       ^
```

Building the library standalone via the scheme switcher works fine, it's only the integration into the Swift project that fails.

Cleaning DerivedData did not help, and the .xcconfig properly references the library both in `OTHER_CFLAGS` and `OTHER_LDFLAGS`.

**Update**

It works if I remove `use_frameworks!` and include the library via the ObjC Bridging header. Is there a way to disable `use_frameworks!` for a single pod?

**Update 2**

With this pod file, it compiles.

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '8.0'

xcodeproj 'xxx' 

target "Frameworks", :exclusive => true do
    link_with "xxx"

    use_frameworks!

    pod ....
end

target "StaticLibraries", :exclusive => true do
    link_with "xxx"

    pod 'iOS-WebP', '0.4'
end
```

Problem is that now when I launch the app, it doesn't seem to find the frameworks:

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/XXX.framework/XXX
>     Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/...
>     Reason: image not found
>   (lldb)

Comment: I think its an issue with the podfile i got the same error.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't disable use_frameworks for a single pod. Best bet is to either copy that pod in manually or just turn off frameworks

Comment: Do you have a source for this? If yes, please add as answer.

Comment: yeah, facing the same problem here. any solutions guys?